# Nodejs zlib throwing a no method error

Tags: node.js

I just installed the ebay-api package through npm. One of it's dependencies is restler and it's throwing an error that I can't seem to fix.

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'gunzip'
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (node_modules/restler/lib/restler.js:428:10)
    at EventEmitter._decode (node_modules/restler/lib/restler.js:161:25)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (node_modules/restler/lib/restler.js:140:14)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:88:20)
    at HTTPParser.onMessageComplete (http.js:137:23)
    at CleartextStream.ondata (http.js:1125:24)
    at CleartextStream._push (tls.js:363:27)
    at SecurePair.cycle (tls.js:679:20)
    at EncryptedStream.write (tls.js:122:13)
    at Socket.ondata (stream.js:38:26)
```

Line 428 is:

```
    zlib.gunzip(buf, callback);
```

I'm running node v0.5.11-pre and the most up-to-date restler install as well. Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Node `0.5.11-pre` does not have the `zlib` helper method `gunzip`.

The current stable version of `restler` is `>= 0.6.0` unfortunately.

You may be able to patch that method on the Node module, but there may very well be other issues. Would upgrading to a stable version of Node be reasonable for you? Even if just to `0.6.0`, which should be very similar to `0.5.11-pre`.

Comment: Thanks, this actually helped. It turns out there were two versions of node installed at the same time on my system. I removed both and then installed nvm so I can manage which version of node is active.

Comment: @VitaliyIsikov Cool, glad you got it figured out.